# Django Rest Framework create user profile on creating django user

Tags: django

I have the following models in my CABSERVICE app:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    is_rider = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_driver = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Rider(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Driver(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cab = models.OneToOneField('Cab', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Cab(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    rn = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Booking(models.Model):
    rider = models.ForeignKey(Rider, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    fare = models.IntegerField()
    src = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dest = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.DurationField()
```

Serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ca
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile

class RiderSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Rider

class DriverSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Driver


class CabSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cab

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    profile = UserProfileSerializer()
    #cab = CabSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'profile')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }

        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username = validated_data['username'],
                password = validate_data['password'],
                email = validate_data['email'])
            profile = validate_data['profile']
            user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user = user, **profile)
            if profile['is_rider']:
                Rider.objects.create(user = user_profile)
            #else if profile['is_driver']:
            #    cab = validate_data['cab']
            #    Driver.objects.create(user = user, cab=cab)
            return user
```

I want to create an api with endpoints as follows:

/drivers/ --GET show all users --POST add new driver

/riders/ --GET show all riders --POST add new rider

/cabs/ --GET show all cabs --POST add new cab

I read that a django application should have only one user authentication model so I extended it to make a user profile referenced by riders and drivers.

NOTE: The driver model has a mapping to cab model.

Please help me achieve such an api structure using django rest framework.

Comment: your question is not clear, you shared your models and saying you want these endpoints, are expecting from us write your whole vewisets?

Comment: I want to understand how do i go about this problem. I am new to django rest framework. Should i create viewsets for all these serializers? Also is my user serializer correctly made? i dont know how to link my cab object to driver user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, better approach would be to have one User model and add a 'role' attribute to the model to indicate that this user is a driver or rider.

in such case, you don't need separate models which could cause you only problems - you will get into issues if you have to select user by id ( is it ID of driver/rider ? etc ..)

something like this:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
     ROLE_CHOICES = (
         ('R', 'rider'),
         ('D', 'driver'),
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
```

For your view, you can create one view to register users and specialize it based on endpoint. Something like this:

```
class RegisterView(generics.CreateAPIView):
   role = None
   def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(role=role)
```

And in your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^drivers/', RegistrationView.as_view(role='driver'), name="driver_register"),
    url(r'^riders/', RegistrationView.as_view(role='rider'), name="rider_register"),
]
```

At this point, you might or might not need to have a user profile, because you can add the user profile information to the user model directly.

Based on your choice to have or not to have user profile, you implement your serializer ( which again will be only one, not multiple )

Of course, you need to tell django to use your model instead of django's user model. But this is easy, just check documentation.

Comment: How would i handle cab information then? A driver is linked with a cab object through one to one relationship. Should I add it to MyUser and keep it blank in case the role is rider?

Comment: depends what is a Cab?  as i see it, cab == driver.  you can add one to one relation to the user model and have it only created where role = 'driver'.

Comment: this logic of creating user objects will be written inside perform_create() ?

Comment: no, perform creste usually serves to add aditional information before calling save of your serializer ( like we do here, passing role information ). you can do it in the serializer's create method which is called as part of save method and after input validation. But in your case,  you can try to use ModelSerializer  and then you can use signals  ( for user profile )